# ADAL Support for Azure B2C UI

Tags: adal

just wondering if there is a build of ADAL that can / should be used with the new Azure B2C features.  The GitHub sample shows how to secure it with Azure B2C, but assumes the user has already authenticated to the web app.  I'm looking for a build that will show the UI with all of the login providers, such as one would display from a native app.  Anything out there yet?  If not, any ETA?

Steve

Comment: Which platform are you interested in?  .NET, iOS, Android, Java, Node?

Comment: There is a version of ADAL.NET for use in native apps with B2C, but we've held it due to a server side bug that is specific to the native .NET scenario.  Hoping to post a sample on [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-overview/) in the next week.

Comment: Ah great, thank you folks, good info.  I'm just interested in .NET at this point Rich, so I'll keep an eye on the page you note above dstrockis.

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the patience

Comment: Is there anyway to authenticate without going through the UI redirects yet? Heard something may be coming for SPA but we just want to control the entire UX process.